# Can't create a bootable device for installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I wish to reinstall ubuntu on my machine, my aim is to clean and make it get back to the default configurations since it got too messy this semester. But I am facing some issues and not sure where is the problem. I tried creating a usb bootable device but the computer send a error message: `a proper digital signature was not found`. I partially solved it disabling signature enforcement from Windows 10 but now I get `The selected bootable device failed`. Already tried bunch of options for creating it, the ISO is downloaded from the official ubuntu's website. Did even tried changing the pen drive I was using. Any solution?

Comment: Most probably you have a corrupt image.

Comment: Did you try in burn the ISO file to a DVD?